# Android share image

Tags: android, share

I wish to make option to share an image to all possible option. eg. mail, WhatsApp, Facebook etc. and I wish when the user share it there will be text addition. For example in Gmail I wish to add headline to mail before sending it, on Facebook also I would like to add text to the image. Do I need to add API to my app? Can you point me to the right direction with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First save the image to your SD card and then use the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + pathToFile));
ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image")); //edit text shown in dialog here
```